# How to keep Gitlab variable masked even the value is changed?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce

We have a masked variable for example called `SECRET_JAMES_BOND` with value `/vault/abc`.  During the pipeline execution, the log shows as `[MASKED]`.   When we changed the value to `ABCDE`, the value was shown.  Even we don't change it, we can easily get the value from the log if we perform `SECRET_JAMES_BOND = $(echo $SECRET_JAMES_BOND) | base64)`.  By echoing the base64 value, it will display on the UI because the value has changed.  When we copy the encoded base64 string and decode it, we get the actual secret.  How can we prevent a masked variable from echoing if its value has been changed ?  Shouldn't masked variables show `[MASKED]` even the value is different from its original value ?

[image]

Comment: Which Runner version you use? Seem that there is a vulnerability for the 13.9.0-rc1
You can check here -> https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/02/18/masked-variable-vulnerability-in-runner-ver-13-9-0-rc1/

Comment: We are currently running self-managed Gitlab 14 `GitLab14.9.3-ee`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can we prevent a masked variable from echoing if its value has been changed

In short: you can't if someone with access is determined to do so.

Masking is not meant to prevent developers with access to control CI steps from revealing secrets through jobs. It is meant to prevent disclosure by accident. There are endless ways that a value could be exfiltrated through the job output it would be impossible to cover them all.

If you wanted to prevent the base64 representation of the secret from being shown, you can register that value as another masked variable, but it must be done in advance.

> Shouldn't masked variables show [MASKED] even the value is different from its original value ?

Good arguments could be made that GitLab should mask some common variations of masked variables, such as base64, url-encoded, backwards, etc. Other CI services (Travis CI for example) do this.

However, this would still be ONLY for the purposes of accidental disclosure.

For example, another way I've seen developers accidentally reveal secrets is by using `curl` with the `-v` flag.

```
script:
  - curl -v https://myusername:${SECRET_JAMES_BOND}@myhost.example.com/secret
```

In the above example, the output of curl will show (in part) an output like:

```
> Authorization: Basic bXl1c2VybmFtZTpzZWNyZXQ=
```

So, if GitLab also masked base64 variations of a password, it would have prevented this accidental disclosure.

But like I mentioned, there's endless ways to output a secret: url-encoding, Caesar cipher, rot-N (rot16, rot24, rot32, etc) or even custom ways like just echoing each character one line at a time, potentially in reverse order.

So, really, you can only realistically prevent accidents, not malicious exfiltration by a user with access to execute code in a job.

Comment: I totally agreed with you.  If a user has a malicious intent, they can find many ways to get the secret.  I would argue that at least Gitlab provide some decent masking even the values has been changed.  I know it can't prevent all scenarios, but at least it prevent from displaying after changing the original value.  It doesn't looks consistent now where i can view after changing the value.

Comment: Yes, I would agree they should mask at least some common scenarios to prevent accidents, like where the password may appear in other forms (like base64 or url encoded)